# upload files to remote host over lftp

Tags: bash, macos, ftp, lftp

I have this script to upload and delete files on my remote host:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Starting Website upload ...
echo This may take some time depending on your internet connection ...
echo Waiting for remote connnection ...

lftp -u server121.web-hosting.com << ftpEOF
    prompt
    cd public_html
    delete index.html
    cd images
    mdelete *.jpg
    cd ..
    lcd /Applications/PlexEmail/streamnet/
    put index.html
    lcd images
    cd images
    mput *.jpg
    bye
ftpEOF

echo Website upload successfull ...
```

After upgrading my Mac to High Sierra 10.13, the ftp command no longer exists.

Any ideas on how to get this to work with lftp?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Install via **homebrew** with `brew install lftp`. See http://brew.sh

Comment: Before moving this to Ask Different, some clarification would be needed. What specifically isn’t working? Do the commands run when you copy paste? Which errors and what error message is presented?